# Spring security facebook authentication plugin with JSON doesn´t create a jsessionid

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a rest API made with Grails, I can use spring security via Ajax auth, and store the jsessionid cookie in the client, but when i login with 'j_spring_security_facebook_json?access_token=' it doesn´t create the jsessionid cookie... and i can´t store the session in the client.

Does exist any solution for this problem? thanks.

Comment: how do you use this api? from which client? just as ajax endpoint from same browser or standalone restful api?

Comment: Android app and iOS app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using an external client (mobile app), in most cases you have to use something different for authenticating your requests. Not a cookie. Usually it's OAuth2 or just a custom signature based on a shared key.

`j_spring_security_facebook_json` auth is supposed to be used as an exchange point, where server can pass a key/token for mobile client that have valid fb token. Then this token could be used for authentication of following requests.

See "How to extend JSON response" at http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/guide/3%20Usage.html#3.5%20Json%20Authentication

Comment: Yes, i´m not using the OAuth2 plugin because i can´t know how to combine with your facebook plugin. I have the FacebookAuthService with custom fields in the 'input Map' but my problem is. How add a oauth2 token to the input map? Thanks Igor, and sorry for my english level.

Comment: it could be anything, oauth2 is just an example, it's for ideal scenario. basically you need any other security filter configured to authenticate mobile clients, you could write your own auth filter if you don't want OAuth